# One item String List into a String in a Haskell program

Tags: haskell

I am using take 1 on a string list, so it takes the first string element from the list and puts it in a new list...

```
I.E: take 1 ["hello", "this", "is", "an", "example"]
```

Would output:

```
["hello"]
```

How can I make it so it outputs just:

```
"hello"
```

Is it easy?

(I only ever want the first element from a string list and I want it to output it as a string).

Comment: Stop...Hoogle time!. [\[String\] -> String](http://haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5BString%5D+-%3E+String), or more general: [\[a\] -> a](http://haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5Ba%5D+-%3E+a)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That would be the `head` function. But be careful: If you call it on an empty list, you'll get an error.

Comment: Yeah I was just about to answer myself saying i've solved it ('unwords' on the take 1 seems to work) Thanks anyway!

Comment: Another option, since String = [Char]: `concat`.